# Did anyone in Harry Potter's generation marry a muggle?

Tags: harry-potter

In Harry Potter's generation, all of the major characters married a wizard or witch, usually someone they met from Hogwarts:

- Harry Potter and Ginny Weasley
- Ron Weasley and Hermione Granger
- Bill Weasley and Fleur Delacour
- Draco Malfoy and Astoria Greengrass
- Neville Longbottom and Hannah Abbott

We know that it is not unheard of for a wizard or witch to marry a muggle. So did anyone in Harry's generation actually marry one? If so, do we know any details about them?

Comment: E.g. according to http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Cho_Chang: Cho Chang eventually married a Muggle. And btw. you're not bound to meeting people at school in order to marry them ;)

Comment: For those who are downvoting, is there something that I can do to improve the question?

Comment: @Thunderforge - I didn’t downvote, but I suspect those who did thought it was too easy (i.e. Cho Chang).

Comment: @Adamant Too easy? Following the trail, it looks info on Cho's husband wasn't in the books or movies, but only revealed in an interview JK Rowling once gave back in 2007. If keeping track of all the details she's revealed in hundreds of interviews over the years is "too easy", then those of us who have just casually read the books will have a hard time asking questions!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

At a book reading [in New Orleans in 2007](http://blog.nola.com/living/2007/10/new_orleans_students_give_rowl.html), Rowling revealed that Cho Chang married a Muggle:

> Cho Chang? “Cho married a Muggle.”

No other details about Cho’s spouse have been revealed canonically.

She’s in Harry’s generation, and I think she’s the closest person to Harry who married somebody non-magical. I don’t *think* anybody from his year married a Muggle.